# JabRef - Is there a plugin or a way to mark entries as "printed" by shortkey?

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I am new to JabRef, therefore searched for this feature already, but could not find any hint to it. So maybe here someone knows how I could quickly mark my entries as *printed*

Basicly it would be enough to have a checkBox or a little icon, like the PDF-Icon for PDF-File-Entries, which would indicate if I already have printed this File or not.

This does not have to be automatic, although this would be great too, but it would be great to have a fast way to set some mark in order to know, which files are available in a printed form for me.

Right now I select every entry I print and add "printed" to the comments, but this annoys me a bit :)

My thanks in advance for any help on this matter!

Comment: BibTeX database files can contain any number of non-standard fields, but JabRef's interface will only do anything special with those it knows. As such, adding a checkbox would require a change in JabRef, which looks like a feature request to me. (Doing it would require Java programming, which is not within the scope of TeX-sx I'm afraid.)

Comment: I was afraid it would be as you said, but wanted to make sure I did not overlooked some available plugin or option, because I am new to this program - thanks - I will forward this to the JabRef developers.